# Unable to dynamically populate a select in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

So I have a set called `manufacturerSet` , I want to create a dropdown with selectable options as the values of this set. The following is my implementation of the dropdown:

```
<select name="maker" value={maker} onChange={(e) => { setMaker(e.target.value) }}>
          {
            Array.from(manufacturerSet).map(make => {
            console.log(make)
            return <option key={make} value={make}>{make}</option>
          })
          }
</select>
```

As you can see im converting the set to an array to be able to map through it. Unfortunately, its not enterring the map itself. output is an empty select with no options.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], including how you define and populate the `manufacturerSet`?

Answer (score 0):

> output is an empty select with no options

What is the original states of both of these? I can see that `maker` is a state... Is it being set from props with useEffect()? And I can't tell what `manufacturerSet` is. Provide a better question and you'll get a better answer.

From the minimum information you've provided, I could guess that your page is rendering and the states haven't been set. But that would be guess. In my experience, when a state comes up empty, it hasn't been initialized.

Review React states: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState

Review useEffect() hook for setting states from data: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect

useEffect() forces the component to re-render every time it's called (which might be once, or every time a specified state changes).

Also, be sure you've added React tools to your developer tools: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

These will help you track the states within each component.